# unable to initialize airflow database after installing airflow

Tags: airflow

I installed on a fresh version of airflow using `Python 3.7.4` on `Mac OS Catalina 10.15.1`.

By running:

```
$ pip install 'apache-airflow[s3,postgres,celery,hdfs,jdbc,hive,slack,crypto,redis]==1.10.4'
```

When I run:

```
$ airflow initidb
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/airflow", line 21, in <module>
    from airflow import configuration
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import LoggingMixin
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .decorators import apply_defaults as _apply_defaults
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py", line 34, in <module>
    from airflow import settings
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 36, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf, AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG  # NOQA F401
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 29, in <module>
    from future import standard_library
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  The `future` module I had was corrupt, so I just re-installed things and it seems to work now.